# ¿Django, Flask y Express son un frame de cliente o de servidor?

Tags: html, django, express, flask

Disculpen mi falta de conocimiento, ya que aun soy nuevo en este tema, pero me gustaría saber lo siguiente:
¿Django, Flask y Express  son un frame de cliente o de servidor?

Comment: ¿Has investigado algo al respecto?

Comment: muy poco realmente

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y se mas claro en la duda que planteas resolver, por ejemplo ¿a qué te refieres con frame?